# Как перенести формы слов: июня, июля, Иисус?

Tags: орфография, морфология, морфемика, перенос

Можно ли перенести следующим образом: ию-ня, ию-ля, Ии-сус?

Comment: Воспользовавшись возможностями программы-редактора, следует исключить переносы недлинных слов. Это делается просто.

Comment: _Это делается просто._ Да, так можно думать, если нет опыта вёрстки сложных текстов в солидных издательствах.

Comment: Без опыта хочется быть в солидных издательствах? Нет опыта, — обрети его.

Comment: Если бы не было, я бы здесь так не умничал :)

Comment: Моя фраза «Нет опыта, — обрети его» риторическая, ни к кому конкретно не относилась.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Можно ли перенести следующим образом: ию-ня, ию-ля, Ии-сус?**

Можно. Нет правил, запрещающих такой перенос. При этом следует учитывать, что непривычные переносы в коротких словах ухудшают восприятие текста, поэтому их следует избегать по возможности. Но в некоторых случаях при вёрстке текста приходится выбирать меньшее из зол.

Вот [ответ на подобный вопрос](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=259762) от Грамота.ру:

> *Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в следующем вопросе: можно ли при переносе слова оставить на строке две гласные
>   буквы, например: аэ-ропорт?*
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Правилами переноса такой перенос не запрещен, его можно признать корректным.

Comment: В примерах даны слова в 4 буквы. Ответ справочной службы касается слова в два раза длиннее. Зачем здесь такой пример приводить?

Comment: Пример я привёл не Вам, а автору вопроса. Вопрос касается не только коротких слов, но и допустимости оставлять отдельно 2 гласные. См. также мой последний комментарий к Вашему ответу (по поводу коротких слов).

Answer (score 1):

Ни в одном из [**правил переноса**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/141-perenos) такая ситуация не описана (с двумя открытыми неприкрытыми слогами в начале слова). Мне, во всяком случае, не попадалась.
Есть правило: **нельзя отрывать от слова одну гласную букву.**
А у нас две подряд: и-ю-ля, и-ю-ня, И-и-сус.
Я бы и их отрывать не стала, опираясь на это же правило.

[**Программа для** **переноса слов**](http://pere-nosim.ru/slovo/%D0%B8%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D1%81) подтверждает:
слова *июля, июня, Иисус* не переносятся на другую строку!

Не переносятся также слова: оазис, аукать, уазик, ионит, Иоанн, воюю, своею.
Но переносятся: ау-ра, ау-дит, Иа-ков, ау-то, Аи-да.

Мне кажется, что не стоит слепо доверять таким ресурсам, а стоит остановиться на том, что все-таки две гласные буковки мы и не оставляем в конце строки, и не переносим (это, конечно, ***мое*** мнение).

[Сравните: **ау-то**, но **ауто-да-фе** — где-то ведь неправильно!]

Answer (score 1):

Запрета переноса коротких слов нет. Но требования дизайна к форматированному тексту предписывают избегать даже висячих строк (команда на запрет есть в Word: http://comp-profi.com/view_post.php?id=642), и наличие остатка слова — тем более фразы — в две буквы будет свидетельством профнепригодности верстальщика.

Кроме запрета на перенос существует возможность управления межбуквенным или междусловным интервалом, т.е. небольшой разрядкой или уплотнением слов в строке — кернингом: http://v-ofice.ru/word/rasstoyanie-mezhdu-bukvami/.

О теории и практике работы с текстом много полезного пишут А. Лебедев и Ю. Гордон.

Comment: _Даже висячих строк..._ Вот это "даже" в данном контексте не очень уместно. **Кёрлинг** — это совсем другой вид спорта. И уплотнение слов с помощью **кернинга**, и висячие строки — это большее зло, чем перенос короткого слова внутри предложения.

Comment: Вы говорили о меньшем зле, теперь о большем. Переносить слово Иисус — зло обыкновенное?

Comment: Я не понимаю Ваших аргументов. Просто посмотрите в словаре, как пишется слово **кернинг** (через **-е-**) и не будем больше спорить. Могу разве что ещё посоветовать посмотреть п.1.4 Мильчина в "Настольной книге издателя", подпункт V.1 про перенос коротких слов. И в той же книге, какими инструментами разрешается уплотнить/разредить строку

Comment: Представьте последним в абзаце перенесённое слово из 4 букв. Его перенос корректен? Что же здесь мудрёного? Выход только один — кернинг.

Comment: В работе верстальщика всегда есть несколько вариантов исправить ситуацию. Но среди них не должно быть уплотнения кернингом (хотя бы без особого согласования с редактором). Варианты я здесь объяснять не буду — задайте для этого отдельный вопрос или посмотрите рекомендованную литературу в предыдущем моём комментарии.